# What is Foobar-umbrella.h for?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks

Assuming I got a Framework called Foobar. When I try compiling my iOS project I get the compiler warning:

> Umbrella header for module 'Foobar' does not include header
>   'Foobar-umbrella.h'

I don't get what this 'Foobar-umbrella.h' is and why it isn't included. Some details about my project:

- An iOS 8 App project mostly written in Swift. A little bit Objective-C
- The 'Foobar' framework is a separate project mostly written in Swift which I have included as a subproject to my main project.
- It has been included by embedding it in build phases and depending on it. But I am not explicitly linking against it.
- I use Cocoapods, but 'Foobar' is not included as a pod.

Answer (score 2):

The umbrella header is the 'master' header file for a framework. Its use is that you can write

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

instead of

```
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <UIKit/UILabel.h>

#import <UIKit/UIButton.h>
#import <UIKit/UIDatePicker.h>
```

and so on.

For me, `<XCTest/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.h>` is included in `<XCTest/XCTest.h>`. Maybe it is not for you? In that case, add the

```
#import <XCTest/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.h>
```

manually.

Comment: I know what an umbrella header is, in my example case it would be Foobar.h. My issue is I don't know what purpose the Foobar-umbrella.h header has which was supposed to be included in the Foobar.h. I am guessing it might be Swift related.